# Python3 decode Bytes Error when running on Raspberry Pi while running correctly on Windows and centos

Tags: linux, python-3.x, decode, raspberry-pi2

**UPDATE:**

Follow n.m.'s comment. I found that I get gzip data on Raspberry-PI. So the solution is `gzip.decompress(res.read())`. But where is the difference between send request from PI, Windows, CentOS?

---

I've written some code to access Web Page with Python. It's running correctly on Windows installed Python 3.4.3 and Centos installed Python 3.2.3

I have a Raspberry Pi, and I want my code run on it. But an Error happens.

```
File "FulibaSign.py", line 26, in <module>
home_content = res.read().decode("GBK")
UnicodeDecodeError: 'gbk' codec can't decode bytes in position 1-2: illegal   multibyte sequence
```

Here are parts of my code

```
headers = {
'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
'Accept-Language': 'zh-cn,en-us;q=0.8,zh;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
'Host': '***',
'Cookie': cookie
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0',
'Referer': '***',
'Connection': 'Keep-Alive'
}

home_page = "***"
req = request.Request(home_page, None, headers)
res = request.urlopen(req)
home_content = res.read().decode("GBK")
```

(**Parts**) res.read() get

````
\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\xcc<is\x1b\xd7\x91\x9f\xa3*\xfd\x87\x11R\x14\xc9\n\t\xcc\x0c.\x82$\x90\xe2%[\xbb\x92\xad\x95\xe8$\xde\xad-\xd4`f\x00\x8c\x08\xcc\x8cg\x06<d\xea\xc7P\x8c\x8f\xd8\xb4MQ\xa4\x0e\x92\x12e\x91\x12%\x8a\x97xz\x95\xd8\xf1\x15g\xbdRV\xb1\x9d\xf2!U\xaa\xf6\xf5\x9b\x1b\x18\x1c\x94\xa8MX\xb6\x00\xbcy\xaf\xbb_\xbf\xee~\xdd\xfdz^\xfb\xa1\xee\x97\xbbz_=\xd1Cd\xb5|\x8e8\xf1J\xe7\xb1\xa3]\x84\xaf9\x10\xf8u\xb0+\x10\xe8\xee\xed&~\xf3b\xef\xf1c\x04\xe5\'\x89^\x85\x11UA\x13$\x91\xc9\x05\x02=/\xf9\x08_V\xd3\xe4\xd6@```\xc0?\x10\xf4KJ&\xd0{20\x08\xb0(\x18l|m\xd6\x1c#\xfd\x9c\xc6\xf9\x12\x07\x0f\xb4c\x8c\x83\xf9\x9c\xa8\xc6=\xe0P\xb1XL\x1f\xaew\xe6\x19\x0e>\xf3\xbc\xc6\x10\xd0\xbb\x99\x7f\xad
````

I am sure the web site's response are encoded by GBK cause
`Content-Type:text/html; charset=gbk`

I run my code by command `python3 ***.py`

on my Raspberry Pi

```
python --version
Python 2.7.3
python3 --version
Python 3.2.3
```

I've even compiled and installed Python 3.2.3 by myself on Raspberry-PI, and I get the same error. Can't figure why.

Comment: You've got a gzipped response. Look at the full respinse headers.

Comment: I found the same code accept different data on Raspberry-PI by WinHEX.

Comment: @n.m. Thanks. Yes, I get correct response by using `gzip.decompress()`. But I still don't know why on Windows or CentOS I can directly get no gzip data, is there any difference when sending request from Raspberry-PI?

Comment: Do you have the same header `'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',` on Windows and CentOS?

Comment: yes, i run the same code on Windows and Raspberry Pi @Armali